# Calculating weeks using two JQueryUI Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

In the image below I show **2 JQuery UI datepicker** which I implemented, now I need to calculate the number of weeks between the 2 dates picked and place them in that form.

I tried using this in one of the datepickers

```
$('#dateF').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        yearRange: '-2:+2',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        //the code below this coment is the important part
        onSelect: function(date, inst) {
            var week = $.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(date));
            alert(week);
        }
```

So I could calculate the start and end week and then subtract them. But the way in which I'm getting the weeks is giving some crazy results that dont make any sense. I dont know what I'm doing wrong if anyone could help me out or give some workaround I'd be very thankful.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is handling the formatted Date within Datepicker..so I tried converting it back and it worked. Try this out:

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      yearRange: '-2:+2',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true   
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      yearRange: '-2:+2',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      onSelect: function(date, inst) {
        // convert date back to mm/dd/yy and get the week #
        var dateObj = $(this).datepicker( 'getDate' );
        var dateTo = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', dateObj);
        var weekto = $.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateTo));

        var dateObj = $('#from').datepicker( 'getDate' );
        var dateFrom = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', dateObj);
        var weekfrom = $.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateFrom));

        // subtract last date from first date's week#
        $('#weeks').empty().append(parseInt(weekto-weekfrom));        
      }
    });
  });
```

HTML:

```
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from" />
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to" />
<br />
Weeks: <span id="weeks"></span>
```

[Working example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/WU9P6/)

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in getting the *Date* from the datepicker, converting it to text and then converting it back into a *Date* again. Just use it directly:

```
  onSelect: function(date, inst) {
    var weekto = $.datepicker.iso8601Week($(this).datepicker('getDate'));
    var weekfrom = $.datepicker.iso8601Week($('#from').datepicker('getDate'));
    // subtract last date from first date's week#
    $('#weeks').text(parseInt(weekto - weekfrom));        
  }
```

You should also cross-populate the *minDate* / *maxDate* options to ensure a valid date range.